# Logout function provides RecursionError error

Tags: python, django

I have this function in views.py:

```
def logout(request):
    logout(request) 
    return HttpResponse('Logged out succesfully!')
```

and this is the error I get when going to /logout

```
RecursionError at /logout/
maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: where do you calling `logout` inside your `logout` function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view named ***`logout(...)`*** is conflicting with the Django's built-in  logout function [**`logout(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.logout). So, change your view name to something other than *logout*,

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout


def my_logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponse('Logged out succesfully!')
```